# Finding a list of instances through followed association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've for a model called `Events`. This model is basically a join table of other 3 models:

```
Events.column_names
=> ["id", "performer_id", "location_id", "date"]
```

In my application I also use the [act_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem, which facilitates the following of different models by a User. In order to do so it creates a Follow table with the following columns:

```
Follow.column_names
=> ["id", "followable_id", "followable_type", "follower_id", "follower_type", "blocked", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

In my `Events` controller I am tring to get a list of all Events where `performer_id` is a performer followed by `current_user`. How would I do this?

I've tried the following without luck:

- act_as_follower has some helpful methods such as
  `book.followed_by?(user)` which returns true or false but I haven't
  been able to make it work inside the query.
- I tried joining the performers table but I haven't been able to make it work either.

Any help appreciated!

**Models:**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base        
  belongs_to :performer
  belongs_to :location
  acts_as_followable
end

class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event
  has_many :location, through: :event
  acts_as_followable
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Event.where(performer: Performer.followed_by(current_user))
```

I don't use the `acts_as_follower` gem, so I'm guessing.

If `acts_as_follower` doesn't support `.followed_by` class method, then perhaps roll your own:

```
class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base 

  class << self 

    def followed_by(thing)
      where(id: Follow.where(followable_type: 'Performer', follower: thing).pluck(:followable_id))
    end 

  end

end
```

BTW, I would think that `Performer` would look more like:

```
class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :locations, through: :events
  acts_as_followable
end
```

Note plural form of `:events` and `:locations`.

Comment: `acts_as_follower` does not support `.followed_by` class method. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!